# LinkedLists: infinite loop

Tags: java, list

Why does the following java code result in an infinite loop?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 3;

    Random rand = new Random();

    LinkedList<Integer> fields = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < n*n; i++) {
        fields.add(i);
    }

    while (fields.size() > 0) {

        // Choose Field
        int f = rand.nextInt(fields.size());

        fields.remove((Integer) f);
        System.out.println(fields.size());
    }
}
   }
```

Comment: what do you see when you step through the code in a debugger?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way you use `remove`, you remove objects by **value**, not by position.

Say your list consists of values `[0, 1, 2, 3]`, and you remove `0` and `1` the first two times. Now you have `[2, 3]`, whose size is 2, so you will never remove `3` now!

To remove by position rather than value, say `fields.remove(f)`. (Notice that `f` is an integer, while `(Integer)f` is an object of the type contained in the list container.)

(Alternatively, for different behaviour, you could continue removing by value, but you should now draw the random number from the range `[min, max]`, where you have to determine the extremal values of the list elements separately. This may take a *lot* longer, of course, since you will have a lot of "misses" where you don't remove anything.)

Answer (score 5):

Because of this line:

```
fields.remove((Integer) f);
```

Remove the `(Integer)` cast and it should work.

There are two flavors of remove in List:

- remove by position: [`remove(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29) and
- remove by contents: [`remove(E)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) (actually it's `remove(Object)` for compatibility reasons)

In your case, E is Integer, and because of autoboxing you are able to cast an int to an Integer. And by doing that, you are choosing the second type, whereas you want the first type.

Comment: Really?  Two instances of `Integer` possessing the same value do not satisfy the equality operations for removal from a list?

Comment: @Kirk this is not about two different Integers, this is about int vs Integer for an overloaded method.

Comment: @Sean, thanks for the edit.  And I agree with glowcoder. ;)  Though arguably it's an epic *method-overloading* fail.  (why in C# it's `Remove` and `RemoveAt`)

Answer (score 2):

You problem comes from the fact that you are actually calling the [remove(Object o)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) method instead of the [remove(int index)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29) method!

When you call `fields.remove((Integer) f);` you do not remove the object at the index `f` but you remove the Integer that is equal to `f` since your List contains `Integer`s

Therefore do not cast `f` into `Integer` and you should be fine.

Also, to get an `Integer` from an `int`, use the [static Integer valueOf(int i)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 3;

    Random rand = new Random();

    LinkedList<Integer> fields = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < n*n; i++) {
        fields.add(i);
    }

    while (fields.size() > 0) {

        // Choose Field
        int f = rand.nextInt(fields.size());

        fields.remove(f);
        System.out.println(fields.size());
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Stepping through the debugger I can see the problem you have is that you are removing numbers which less than the size.  To start with that number will be there however, unless you remove the largest number the first time it will never be removed.

What you are trying to do is to select numbers in a random order.  The simplest way to do this is to use Collections.shuffle()

```
int n = 3;
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++)
  list.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(list);
System.out.println(list);
```

prints

```
[7, 4, 0, 8, 5, 1, 3, 6, 2]
```